# Create new record when save button is clicked instead of overwrite MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a form with a combox box and a text box that are bound to a table, there is also a table displaying the contents and a button to save the reocrd.

I was wondering how do I have the form create a new record instead of overwriting the current one when the save button is clicked ?

I am currently using a macro which has a RunCommand SaveRecord and a Refresh to update the table.

Will I need to use vba code to achieve what I am looking ?

[image]

Comment: can you show us your current codes ?

Comment: beware of primary key ..

Comment: The primary key is auto-generated for each record. I dont actually have any code I was using embedded macros for the on clcick event. I inserted a screenshot into the Question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simplest answer would be to build a quick macro in VBA - the code to add a new record to a table is pretty simple:

```
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

  Set dbVideoCollection = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName") //<- Or a specific query in the parentheses.

  rs.AddNew
  rs("Column1").Value = "Blah"
  rs("Column2").Value = "Blah"
  rs("Column3").Value = "Blah"
  rs("Column4").Value = "Blah"
  rs("Column5").Value = "Blah"
  rs.Update
End Sub
```

You can pull the data from the text boxes (or whatever input you're using) on your form by adding variables and reading that data in, such as:

```
strPnum = Me.txtPNum.Value
```

Here is the code that I'm using for a similar program - it's more complex, but its adding rows based on criteria in the database and input on the form.

```
Private Sub Add()
''Add the Item to the Database

Dim Checker As Integer      ''Used to check if all of the essential information is present on the form
Dim strPNum As String       ''Hold's the Parent Item Value
Dim strSIM As String        ''Hold's the SIM number Value
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset     ''Used for the Routing table record set
Dim lrs As DAO.Recordset    ''Used for the Labor Code table record set
Dim db As Database          ''Database variable
Dim i As Integer
Dim OpDesc, LabCode, DBLRCodes(50), DBLRClong, DBLRDesc(50), a As String
Dim RoutSeq, LabHour, LabUnits, LRChecker, b, c As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblTestForRoutingInput")
Set lrs = db.OpenRecordset("tblLaborRateCodes")
Checker = 0
i = 1

''Debug.Print "For Cycling through manually."

''Verify that the essential fields have values.
If IsNull(Me.txtPNum.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Please enter a value for the Parent Item Number", vbOKOnly, "Blank Parent Item Number")
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtSIM.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Please enter a value for the SIM number", vbOKOnly, "Blank SIM Number")
ElseIf Len(Me.txtSIM.Value) <> 11 Then
    Checker = MsgBox("The SIM # must be 11 characters.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid SIM Number")
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtStep1.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Please enter at least ( 1 ) routing step.", vbOKOnly, "No Routing Steps")
End If



''If none of the essential fields are empty, proceed with the add.
If Checker = 0 Then

    ''Pull the Parent Item and SIM number values
    strPNum = Me.txtPNum.Value
    strSIM = Me.txtSIM.Value

    ''Search the table to see if the PNum or SIM already exists. If it does, end the function.
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs("Parent_Item") = strPNum And Checker = 0 Then
            Checker = MsgBox("Parent Item#: " + strPNum + " already exists in the database. If you wish to edit the item, please use the [Edit] screen.", vbOKOnly, "Item Already Exists")
            i = 20
        ElseIf rs("SIM") = strSIM And Checker = 0 Then
            Checker = MsgBox("SIM#: " + strSIM + " already exists in the database. If you wish to edit the item, please use the [Edit] screen.", vbOKOnly, "Item Already Exists")
            i = 20
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    ''Determine the step to read in.
    Do Until i = 20
        If i = 1 Then
            OpDesc = Me.txtStep1.Value
            RoutSeq = Me.txtSeq1.Value
            LabCode = Me.txtCode1.Value
            LabHour = Me.txtHours1.Value
            LabUnits = Me.txtUnits1.Value
        ElseIf i = 2 Then ''I have a long string of If statement in the original code that are just used to get the data from the different text boxes but would take up another few hundred lines here.
        End If


        ''If the current step has no data, end the function
        If IsNull(OpDesc) Then
            Checker = MsgBox("Item: " + strPNum + " has been added with (" + Str(i - 1) + ") Routing Steps", vbOKOnly, "Item Added")
            i = 20
        Else
            ''Define the variables to use for the Labor Rate Checker
            LRChecker = 0
            DBLClong = ""
            b = 0
            c = 1
            ''Check the entered Labor Rate Code against what is in the database, and pull the data into parallel arrays
            Do While Not lrs.EOF
                b = b + 1
                If LabCode = lrs("Labor_Rate_Code") Then
                    LRChecker = 1
                End If
                DBLRCodes(b) = lrs("Labor_Rate_Code")
                DBLRDesc(b) = lrs("Labor_Rate_Description")
                lrs.MoveNext
            Loop ''While Loop

            ''Compile the LR array data into 1 string for the Message Box
            Do Until c > b
                If DBLClong = "" Then
                    DBLClong = DBLRCodes(c) + " - " + DBLRDesc(c)
                Else
                    DBLClong = DBLClong & vbNewLine & DBLRCodes(c) + " - " + DBLRDesc(c)
                End If
                c = c + 1
            Loop ''Until Loop

            lrs.MoveFirst

            ''If the Labor Rate code entered does not match one in the system, prompt the user to input a new code.
            If LRChecker = 0 Then
                LabCode = InputBox("The Labor Rate Code entered for Routing Step: " + Str(i) + " does not match any in the database. Please enter one of the following codes: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & DBLClong + ".", "Invalid Labor Rate Code", "Enter Code Here")
            End If

            ''Add the new record into the DB
            rs.AddNew
            rs("Parent_Item") = strPNum
            rs("Operation_Description") = OpDesc
            rs("Routing_Sequence") = RoutSeq
            rs("Labor_Code") = LabCode
            rs("Labor_Hours") = LabHour
            rs("Labor_Units") = LabUnits
            rs("Quantity") = 10000
            rs("SIM") = strSIM
            rs("Effective_Date") = Date
            rs.Update
            i = i + 1
        End If


    Loop
    ''Close the recordsets
    rs.Close
    lrs.Close

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have just realised that this is creating 1 extra record at the start and it then updates to last added record. Any idea how I get rid of this ? I have tryed taking out the .Update and no luck

Comment: I'm using a similar macro in an ACCESS db, and I'm not seeing the same thing happen. You could try adding 'rs.MoveLast' before the 'AddNew' command. I'll upload the code that I'm using so you can take a look at it.

Comment: @andrewmours I think your method works if the form is not bound, otherwise, it automatically creates a new record.